# I am working on project and my rsult query give a multiple records but i want to each record at one time only, i used inner join into this query?

Tags: codeigniter

```
$this->db
    ->select(array('courses.Course_Name','teacher.First_Name','teacher.Last_Name','teacher.Reg_Id','teacher_assignment.Assignment_Id','Assignment_Url','assignment.Solution_Url','assignment.Status','courses.Course_Id')); 
$this->db
    ->from(array('student_registration')); 
$this->db
    ->join('courses','student_registration.Course_Id=courses.Course_Id','inner'); 
$this->db
    ->Join('teacher_assignment','teacher_assignment.Course_Id=courses.Course_Id','inner'); 
$this->db
    ->Join('assignment','assignment.OEN_Number = student_registration.OEN_Number','teacher_assignment.Reg_Id = assignment.Reg_Id','inner'); 
$this->db
    ->Join('teacher','teacher.Reg_Id = assignment.Reg_Id','inner'); 
$this->db
    ->where(array('student_registration.OEN_Number'=> $uid)); 

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: use `$query = $this->db->get()->row();` for single record

Comment: i strongly recommend to read your own question - it should be obvious nobody can answer this based on your informations . at least provide your table structure with some sample data, this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156729/how-do-i-display-data-in-a-table-structure should help, and describe exactly what you want